# How to greayout back button and view source of browser

Tags: javascript, java

How do u greayout backbutton or view source of browser so users can't click backbutton and view source code because javascript contains lot of business logic code. I need to greayout those options so users can't be able to click them. i recently joined banking project and i am beginner in java and development.

Comment: You cant control browser buttons via javascript, it will be a big security issue. For sites to work, javascript source will always be available and users can alwasy see it. You can obfuscate it though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding this in the Head section of your html file:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.history.forward();
    function noGoingBack() {
        window.history.forward(); 
    }
</script>
```

And add this in your Body section:

```
<body onload="noGoingBack();" onpageshow="if (event.persisted) noBack();" onunload="">
```

This prevents the page from going back.